# Format disk for SQL server

Tags: sql-server

MSSQL server 2016

I've discovered that disks under SQL has not been  formatted in 64k and I would like to fix it.
Please advice the best way to have sql data/log on disk with 'byte per cluster' = 64k

Thank you.

Comment: read: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-and-format-a-hard-disk-partition-bbb8e185-1bda-ecd1-3465-c9728f7d7d2e

Comment: IMO opinion it's a lot of work & risk for little benefit, wait until you are going to replace the server anyway